# How to use LIMIT in spring within sql query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Somehow I cannot use the `LIMIT` qualifier within a sql query using `Spring-data-jpa`:

```
@Query("SELECT p from Person p WHERE p.company.id = :id ORDER BY p.name DESC LIMIT 3")
```

What is wrong here?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Limit near line 1, column 146
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: May [this](http://gal-levinsky.blogspot.de/2012/06/spring-data-jpa-limit-query-size.html) help.

Comment: Ok that at least works, though I though I could somehow use `LIMIT` keyword directly in the sql statement...

Comment: I think LIMIT is highly vendor specific. With JPA you could do q.setMaxResults(limitVal)

Comment: @membersound You aren't writing SQL you are writing HQL. Very different things. If it would be a SQL query it would work, it doesn't work in HQL.

Comment: You may find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255394/jpa-native-query-get-a-single-object [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63600700/6614803](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63600700/6614803)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`LIMIT` is not part of JPQL. The mechanism available in current release version (1.6.0.RELEASE as of the time of writing) is pagination:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  @Query("...")
  List<Person> findLimited(..., Pageable pageable);
}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
repository.findLimited(..., new PageRequest(0, 10));
```

This will return the first ten results of the query defined in the `@Query` annotation.

The current master branch of Spring Data JPA already contains a new feature that would allow you to rewrite above query as follows:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  List<Person> findTop3ByCompanyOrderByName(Company company);
}
```

As of version 1.7.0.M1 (feature [already available](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/43d035fe545e8ec1f82b5b3cafeca819423feeec) in [snapshots](http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.7.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/)) the query derivation mechanism will understand `Top` and `First` in the subject clause To limit the number of results returned.

**Update**
as `new PageRequest` deprecated you need to use`PageRequest.of(0, 10)` instead

Comment: how to do if i need to use @Query because existing derivation mechanisms are not enough but I still want to limit the number of results? Putting TOP or LIMIT in the query does not work as others said and putting TOP in the method name will not work since the derivation mechanism is disabled when using Query, Should I still use the pagination approach?

Answer (score 27):

You can use the nativeQuery like this :

```
@Query(value="SELECT * from person p WHERE p.company_id = :id ORDER BY p.name DESC LIMIT 3", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my Spring Boot 2.3.6 project. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use HQL instead of the Spring-data-jpa and then use `setMaxResults()`.

For example:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Person WHERE company.id = :id ORDER BY name DESC");
query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setMaxResults(3); // this replaces the LIMIT in the query
List<Person> personList = query.getResultList();

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```