# JPA Native query get a Single Object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

How can i get a single object by using JPA Native query. I did some researches but all give an answer is use "getSingleResult", however it didn't return what i want to get. For example, what should i do if i want to get a count of table in my database and fetch it into a Integer.

This code below shows how i get this by using Sessison hibernate:

```
int check = Integer.parseInt((String) sessionF.createSQLQuery("select to_char(count(*)) as count from user_tables where table_name upper('TEST')").uniqueResult());
```

And what i hope to be fine in JPA:

```
int check = Integer.parseInt((String) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select to_char(count(*)) as count from user_tables where table_name upper('TEST')").getSingleResult());
```

Obviously, the code doesn't return what i want. Therefore, please help me to cope with this problem. Thank you !

Comment: which seems to be a query that you could use JPQL for ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With JPA you need to do like following

```
int num = ((Number)this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from your_table_name")
                .getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

**edited :**

```
 String name = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select t.name from your_table_name t limit 1").getSingleResult().toString();
```

you will got count with num object

Hope its will help to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. This return a correct result. But what i hope is a way to get the value of a object which i query from Database. What should i do if i want to get the object like: "select name from table_test where id = 1".

Comment: you need to do like my edited answer   
*String name = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select t.name from your_table_name t limit 1").getSingleResult().toString();*

Comment: Hi Ravi, sorry for late replying. Its worked fine, thank you a alot

Answer (score 3):

In case of native query with multiple select expressions returns an `Object[]` (or `List<Object[]>`).

you can use below example code as per your requirement .

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, userId);
Object[] result = (Object[])q.getSingleResult();
String id= result[0];
int name = result[1];
```

You might need to typecast the result `Array` values.

Comment: If there is no results from query JPA throw the NoResultException.

Answer (score 2):

This may help someone.
To get a single object you can choose either of the below:

Method 1:

```
Query theQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from yourTable where yourTableId = (Select MAX(yourTableId) from yourTable where empId = ?1 and instId = ?2 GROUP BY empId,instId)",YourTableEntity.class);
theQuery.setParameter(1, empId);
theQuery.setParameter(2, instId);
System.out.println(theQuery.getSingleResult());
```

Method 2:

```
Query theQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from yourTable where empId = ?1 and instId = ?2 order by yourTableId DESC");   
theQuery.setParameter(1, empId);
theQuery.setParameter(2, instId);
theQuery.setMaxResults(1); //Use if it makes good impact in complexity
System.out.println(theQuery.getResultList().get(0));
```

NOTE: For simplicity sake I just printed it. You may need to typecast.
Check if the time taken by method 1 or method 2 works better for you.